# How to handle wait processing other than time.sleep

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate web operations using Selenium, but I'm having trouble getting it to wait for anything other than `time.sleep`.

I tried to wait using `WebDriverWait` as shown in the code below:

###### applicable section

```
# If I used time.sleep, I was able to process it, but if I use WebDriverWait, the following error is displayed
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
# time.sleep(20)
```

###### code full text

```
# Importing libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
import datetime
# Specify the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

URL = 'http://localhost/login'

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=30)

try:
    EXEC_TIME = datetime.datetime.now()
    MAIL_ADDRESS = 'hogehoge@gmail.com'
    PASSWORD = 'Password'

    print(EXEC_TIME)

    ## login
    driver.get(URL)

    login_action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

    # input mailaddress
    email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/input')
    login_action.move_to_element_with_offset(email_box, 5, 5)
    login_action.click()
    login_action.send_keys(MAIL_ADDRESS)

    # input password
    password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')
    login_action.move_to_element_with_offset(password_box, 5, 5)
    login_action.click()
    login_action.send_keys(PASSWORD)

    login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button')
    login_action.move_to_element_with_offset(login_btn, 5, 5)
    login_action.click()

    login_action.perform()

    # wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
    # time.sleep(20)

    side_menu_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/label')
    if side_menu_btn.is_displayed():
        print(side_menu_btn.is_displayed()) # => True
        side_menu_btn.click()
    else:
        print(side_menu_btn.is_displayed())

  
    print("Finish")
except Exception as e:
    print("Occured error")
    print(e)
```

but I got the following error:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <label for="drawer-checkbox" class="drawer-btn">...</label> is not clickable at point (32, 104). Other element would receive the click: <div class="vld-background"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.55)
```

With the method using `time.sleep`, I was able to do the process itself, but the result of the process becomes unstable when using `time.sleep`, so I would like to implement a wait based on the content.

Comment: Your error shows element not clickable while in your code snippet, there is no reference of click. It means your error is coming not at this place. Please share your other part of code where you are trying to click.

Comment: @QualityMatters Thanks for taking the time to comment! I've added the clickable processing part.

Comment: Why do you think that `<label>` tag can be clicked?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks.When I used time.sleep, I was able to move to the next page by clicking on this label